# Remove specific characters on the right of a string

Tags: php, string, number-formatting, trim, money-format

I need to remove zeros from the end of a string, but only up to 2 places from the right of a decimal point.

I'got a formatted price being handed over as a string, and that price is up to 5 decimal places.  I need to strip unnecessary zeros from the price but leaving at least 2 to the right of a decimal place.  For example:

£0.00230 -> £0.0023
and
£1.50000 -> £1.50

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Your expected output is confusing `£0.00230 -> £0.0023` the result is 4 decimal places, yet your question suggests you only want 2 decimal places??

Comment: I should say, as it looks like i'm being flamed already(!), that I can use rtrim to trim the zero's off, but I cant find a way to get it not to trim zero's to the right of a decimal place character.

Comment: where the price is 2 decimal places, such as £1.50, yes I need it to display that but its displaying £1.50000

Comment: can you show us what you have tried so we can fix it??

Comment: sure... 

<?php echo rtrim($trimmedprice,"0"); ?>

Comment: why not use round($price, $decimalSignificance)? You only need to make a condition if you want otherwise, then you may use `sprintf("%01.2f", $price);` or something similar?

Comment: Yeah, i didnt down vote you, but i still dont understand what you want to achieve. If you want 2 decimal places then i would expect the 1st example to be `£0.00230 -> £0.00` Im sure this question can be answered, but you need to explain the rules in more detail

Comment: Sorry Steve wasn't implying you did :)

Thing is I only need 2 decimal places where a price only needs to show 2 places, such as £1.50 - but prices that use more than 2 decimals should show as such, for example £0.0023.

now using rtrim to strip right zero's works to a point but it strips too many when you get to 2 decimal point prices.  I appreciate that its not made any easier by the fact I'm having to manipulate a string.

So what I'm trying to achieve in a nutshell, is to strip all right hand zero's but not the 2 zero's to the right of a decimal point character.

Comment: Ok, i understand now - i added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Final and last update hopefully... trim off all the zeros on the right then add 1 or 2 zeroes if needed.

```
function format_number($price) {
    if (preg_match('~^£\d+$~', $price)) {
        $price .= '.00';
    } else {
        $price = rtrim($price, '0');
        if (preg_match('~\.$~', $price)) {
            $price .= '00';
        } elseif (preg_match('~\.\d$~', $price)) {
            $price .= '0';
        }
    }
    return $price;
}
echo format_number('£230') . "\n";
echo format_number('£230.12') . "\n";
echo format_number('£23.024') . "\n";
echo format_number('£230.00024') . "\n";
echo format_number('£230.0240') . "\n";
echo format_number('£230.2') . "\n";
```

Output:

```
£230.00
£230.12
£23.024
£230.00024
£230.024
£230.20
```

Comment: I just notice `money_format()` will be undefined under Windows :(, guess it s Linux time

Comment: Thanks clayton just tried this but its rounding 5 decimal places to 2.

Comment: Yah, made this post when I was running out the door and overlooked that part of your post, will update my answer when I get home

Comment: I updated my answer with a simple solution.  It treats the number as a string and will only trim 1, 2, or 3 zeros at the end of the string if they exist.

Comment: This also assume the strings you have always go to 5 decimal places but that's what it sounded like based on your post.  If I'm incorrect, you may want to try one of the answers here since I'm done for the day, haha

Comment: Hi Clayton - I've applied your code but it doesn't appear to be adding the 2nd zero after the decimal, i.e. £1.8 instead of £1.80

However it is working with prices £0.01200 are correctly showing as £0.012 :)

Comment: Question: does the price ever look like £150? and then you need to change it to £150.00?  In the last else-if condition I added something for that, you can remove the last else-if if you don't need it.

Comment: yes good point, i just noticed £1 products are displaying as £1 not £1.00

Comment: okay, just updated my code once more... does that cover all the potential formats?

Comment: Fantastic yes that now seems to be displaying everything correctly, thank you Clayton :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$value = "0.00230";
$new_value = explode(".", $value);
$substring = substr($new_value[1], 0, 1);

if($substring == "00"){
  $value = number_format($value, 4, '.', '');
} else {
  $value = number_format($value, 2, '.', '');
}
echo $value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the symbol, cast to float to remove trailing zeros, and use `number_format` to add them back if needed:

```
function fixCurrency($string, $symbol){

    //remove £, and any trailing zeros
    $val = (float) ltrim($string, $symbol);
    //add back zeros if needed
    $parts = explode('.', $val);
    if(!isset($parts[1]) || strlen($parts[1]) < 2){
        $val = number_format($val, 2);
    }
    return $symbol . $val;

}
```